# Is there a commonly adopted working Spring interface between Apache Kafka and Websockets that doesn't involve the in-memory message broker?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, websocket

I am looking for a working, robust and commonly used Spring / Spring boot interface between Apache Kafka and Websockets which does not use the 'simple in-memory message broker'. In other words, the WebSockets endpoint(s) can be easily - or even programmatically - wired into Kafka; even if it means reading off whatever WS endpoint and using the KafkaTemplate (or whatever) to .send(message) to Kafka and reversing the process for subscriptions. I'm looking to cut out the additional unnecessary (and, I think, unreliable) middle-person. I think the 'architecture' I'm looking for is this:

client1|<<==HTTP/WebSockets messages==>>server-side JAVA WS / Kafka API magic<<===messages===>>Apache Kafka
client2|
...
clientN|

There will be a database, storage and various business functions in the middle layer also but I've omitted them for the sake of 'diagram' simplicty.

The only client-facing code / process should be the HTTP server which hosts whatever pages including the WebSockets server-side code (or calls out to some other back-end server with that code on it). The Kafka broker will be hidden behind all that, alone in the darkness where no hackers may interrupt its mystical reflections and sinister processes.

There are numerous tutorials and examples which get tantalizingly close to what I'm after. But all of them use the 'simple in-memory message broker at the end of the WebSockets part' which I think is not a production-grade solution. I think it should be possible to glue the WebSockets directly on to Kafka and various articles seem to suggest this has been done but when I go looking, it kind of also doesn't. The only things that come close on GitHub haven't been touched for years and even on first glance are far behind the current version of Spring boot etc and would not work as currently coded without using the older versions of the various APIs they depend on.

Maybe this means they all coalesced into an uber-API around 2021/22 which everyone now uses and for some reason doesn't readily appear in my searches. It seems WebFlux may be the answer but I haven't seen the exact example of what I'm trying to do. It always seems to involve POST requests and suchlike. I want WebSockets going both ways.

Any help appreciated.

I have so far:

- worked through loads of Kafka / websockets tutorials
- a lot of google searches
- a lot of trawling through code on Github
- tried to find the same functionality using WebFlux

Comment: Use Apache Pulsar instead... It has Kafka client compatibility and a websocket api. Kafka just isn't really designed to be used this way

Comment: Thanks. To clarify, by this, do you mean using web-cleint<--WS-->Pulsar<-->Kafka? Or do you mean, just don't use Kafka and use Pulsar / WS instead? I read the Pulsar About docs and it seems Pulsar is a fairly heavy duty message broker itself so may obviate the need for Kafka.

Comment: Correct. Kafka isn't necessary. Nor offers anything related to websockets

Comment: Ok, thanks. I tried to mark your answer best but the instructions don't work (sorry, new here).

Comment: You cannot mark comments as answers, only upvote them with enough rep